# What happened to my GIF app in Messages?

Tags: ios, messages

I can no longer see the app button next to my bar in messages. How can I restore this it regain my access to the icon

Comment: Which app would this be? Did you upgrade/install anything since it worked as expected? Can you add a screenshot (edited to show where the app *should* be)? Is is still listed if you tap the + sign at left and then the „more“ link?

Answer (score 1):

In iOS 17, it is now a big Plus button on the bottom left. Tapping that gives you a list of apps and stickers.